# Assign different variables to different classes

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I'm following along a Python tutorial series and I've come to classes.
So.. I'm trying to make some kind of "medevial RPG class system" and are trying to fetch weapons to a warrior class. Im really new to this so would be thankful if you guys explained it as easy as possible.

So, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Warrior' object has no attribute 'wep_name'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.health = 100
        self.name = name
        self.equipment = {

        "Weapon": 'None',
        "Attack Damage": '0'
        }

    def printName(self):
        print "Name: " + self.name


class Warrior(Character):
    """
    **Warrior Class**
    50%  more HP
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Warrior, self).__init__(name)
        self.health = self.health * 1.5
        self.equipment["Weapon"] = self.wep_name      # <-- ?

class Weapon(object):
    def __init__(self, wep_name):
        self.wep_name = wep_name
```

And sorry if the title makes no sense. I'm not really sure what this is called :(

Answer (score 2):

At the line containing the error, `self` refers to a `Warrior`, not a `Weapon`, so it has no `wep_name`. If you want to make a new `Weapon` at that point, it might be something like:

```
    self.equipment["Weapon"] = Weapon("Sword")
```

Answer (score 1):

As your have no weapon member variable inside your warrior class you cannot assign it.

You will have to supply it to your init method like so

```
def __init__(self, name, wep_name)
```

like you do in the weapon class.

now you can do

```
self.equipment["Weapon"] = wep_name
```

else consider referring to an instance of the weapon class which already encapsulates the weapon_name

hope this helps you out